# What is the math behind Buffett's 2015 Per-Share Investments figure for Berkshire Hathaway?

Tags: investing, stock-analysis, balance-sheet, value-investing

Multiplying the $159,794 figure by 1.6m shares gets me $262,541,542,000.00.

Here's what I did to try and reproduce that figure (amounts in millions):
[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBeBi.png)

Which is about 10 billion dollars off. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[Here's the 2015 Berkshire Hathaway Annual Report I'm referring to.](http://www.berkshirehathaway.com/2015ar/2015ar.pdf)

Comment: It's probably a rounding error.  Class A shares outstanding is 1,643,183, per page 38.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! However, it didn't change the numbers too much--I come out to roughly $253bb but Buffett's is still $262.5bb.

Comment: All of the balance sheet numbers are also rounded to the millions.  It's probable that the Buff man has access to unrounded numbers.

Comment: @quid--It's hard to imagine that rounding error to the order of a million would add up to a ten billion dollar difference, right? I don't think there are that many factors in the summation to Total Investments that I linked above such that rounding errors would add up to ten billion dollars. What's more believable is I missed something in the balance sheet.

Comment: You're right!  So page 62 indicates the Kraft Heinz "fair value" at 23,679 for common stock and 8,363 for the preferred for a total "fair value" of 32,042.  That's $8,618 more than the "carrying value" (which is what's listed in the balance sheet).  There are probably a couple of other variations from the carrying value on these investments combined with some rounding error to come to the number he quotes in his preface letter.

Comment: Brilliant! Great catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Heinz investment is fair value instead of carrying value :)

Comment: It was a fun puzzle!